# Trying to create a virtualenv in python and activate it

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I am having a hard time to create a virtualenv in Python and activating it. I am working on the **Windows** Operating system.

In command prompt,

I have installed virtualenv by typing the following command:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then, to create a virtual environment in it, I used the following:

```
virtualenv ENV
```

But, I am not sure if this right.

Next, I am unable to understand how to activate it.
For Linux, i found that activation would be done using ***source /bin/activate***.
But, unable to find the one for Windows.

Please help me out in creating the virtualenv and activating it.

Comment: from: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/  On Windows, the equivalent activate script is in the Scripts folder: `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've installed it correctly.  The command you gave: `virtualenv ENV` will create a folder called `ENV` and place the installation inside it.

The dictionary will be created in the path specified in the shell.

IE if when running it said :

```
C:\Users\UserName>virualenv ENV
```

the `ENV` folder will be placed int `C:\Users\UserName`.

This is absolutely fine.  Note that you don't have to call it `ENV` all the time though.

---

To activate you would need to navigate (in the shell using the command `cd`) to the location where virtualenv is installed. Once there you enter

```
ENV\Scripts\activate
```

activate is a batch script that will change your terminal to have `(ENV)` (or whatever filename you choose at the beginning of the shell path.  When you see this it tells you it has been activated.

---

To stop the virtual environment you need to use `deactivate`. This can be used in the same way.  IE like this:

```
ENV\Scripts\deactivate
```

---

## Just in case your using PowerShell and not Command Prompt:

On PowerShell there are execution policies.  This means there are additional actions that apply:

Before starting allow all scripts on the system must be digitally signed to execute.  You can do it like this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
```

When you create your virtual environment you use:

```
virtualenv .\ENV
```

(notice the `.\` instead of just the folder name)

Next to run use the similar (but different) command:

```
 .\ENV\scripts\activate
```

(once again notice the `.\`)

When prompted you will need to accept the execution just enter `Y`.  It has been activated.

The [virtualenv instructions are here for complete reference](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/)

Answer (score 3):

Can you explain why would you want to activate it?
From [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

> You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation
>   just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path,
>   so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter
>   and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full
>   path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should
>   be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual
>   environment’s Python automatically.

On the same link you can see the commands you need with more information.

P.S. Take a look at another packaging tool, [Pipenv](http://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is easy and will save your time. I highly recommend it.

Comment: yaa pyhazard, i will be running a small text file by using the command: pip install packages.txt. which installs my packages

Answer (score 0):

virtual environment is used to create the room where you can use the specific package for specific project.

to Activate the virtualenv in linux.

once you installed the `virtualenv` in system

use the command,

```
ritik@ritik-MS-7A15:~$ virtualenv jog
```

these command creates An virtualenv

2.To Activate the virtualenv

```
ritik@ritik-MS-7A15:~$ source hog/bin/activate
```

these command will Activate the virtual environment.And you'll get this

(hog) `ritik@ritik-MS-7A15:~$`

3.To deactivate the virtualenv use

(hog) `ritik@ritik-MS-7A15:~$ deactivate`

it will deactivate the virtual environment

Comment: Hi @ritik20, the original question was about activating virtual env on Windows, not Linux. If you can provide an answer for Windows, that would be helpful. Thanks.