# Properly activate my virtual environment file in windows cmd

Tags: python-3.x, windows, virtualenv

how do I properly activate my virtual environment file in windows cmd? I've searched for the equivalent translation for "source" but I've not found anything successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to create a virtualenv in python and activate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307078/trying-to-create-a-virtualenv-in-python-and-activate-it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+how+activate

Answer (score 0):

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

| Platform | Shell | Command to activate virtual environment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POSIX | bash/zsh | `$ source <venv>/bin/activate` |
|  | fish | `$ source <venv>/bin/activate.fish` |
|  | csh/tcsh | `$ source <venv>/bin/activate.csh` |
|  | PowerShell Core | `$ <venv>/bin/Activate.ps1` |
| Windows | cmd.exe | `C:\> <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat` |
|  | PowerShell | `PS C:\> <venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1` |

Comment: The <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat did the trick. I'm very grateful for  assistance thank you very much.